# "available in the store" Or "available in-store"

Tags: word-choice

Suppose that you are showing a store clerk a picture of a particular computer. You have a question for him:

> (1) *Is this computer available **in the store**?*
> (2) *Is this computer available **in-store**?*

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

"In-store" is increasingly being used alongside "online": "This computer is available in-store and online". You might ring, email or text the store and ask "Is this available in-store, because I'd really like to look at it and use the one on display".

If you actually in the store, you have choices including: "Is this (computer) available in this store?" (I think better than "in the store") or "Is this (computer) available here?". You *could* ask "Is this available in-store?" but this isn't standard usage yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the 1st sentence, it just says that it's available in the store.

I wouldn't prefer the 2nd sentence since "in-store" sounds a bit strange.

Just the normal "in the store" is better.